# JQuery: Validator.SetDefaults for a single form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using JQuery validation and I have some custom logic inside showErrors for displaying errors.

```
     var form = $('#container').find('#form1');
     form.data('validator', null); //doing this so that newly added DOM elements are picked up.

            $.validator.setDefaults({

              showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
                  ......
                  .....
              }
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form); 
form.validate();
```

This works absolutely fine. But the validator defaults are being set for all the forms on my page which I don't want. I'm interested just in setting the defaults for just form1

Also for some reason the below does not work for me.So I had to go with the above code and set the showErrors through $.validator.setDefaults.

```
form.validate({
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
     .....
     ////
}
});
```

Any ideas on how to set the default showErrors for a single form on my page?

Comment: It would have been great to mention that you're using a Microsoft framework.  Since this uses the Microsoft Unobtrusive Validation plugin, it totally interferes with how the jQuery Validate plugin normally works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. Hope this helps someone running into a similar issue.

Setting :

`form.data("validator").settings.showErrors = "..."` did the trick for me.

Comment: This only matters when using a Microsoft framework along with its Unobtrusive Validation plugin.